# Strange behaviour of the 'r' key on keyboard

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard

I have an Arch Linux machine whose 'r' key started misbehaving recently. This only happens when the language is set to English (in another language, it works correctly), which makes me suspect it's *not* a mechanical problem.

Basically, the 'r' key sometimes emits a '*' instead of an 'r'. This seems to happen *absolutely* at random without any rhyme or reason. This happens in all applications with equal randomness.

What could possibly cause this, and how would I go about diagnosing and fixing this?

Comment: Could it be related to number lock?

Comment: Try using `xev`  (under some desktop environment)